# is it possible to fix the kubectl file copy issue

Tags: kubernetes

I want to copy files from kubernetes pod into the local machine, but shows error like tihs:

```
> kubectl cp texhub-server-service-6f8d688c77-kvhgg:"/app/core.21" /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/core.21
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
Dropping out copy after 0 retries
error: unexpected EOF
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? I have already tried to add the retries parameter, still facing this issue:

```
> kubectl cp texhub-server-service-6f8d688c77-kvhgg:"/app/core.21" /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/core.21 --retries=3
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
Resuming copy at 888832 bytes, retry 0/3
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
Resuming copy at 1505280 bytes, retry 1/3
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
Resuming copy at 2125824 bytes, retry 2/3
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
Dropping out copy after 3 retries
error: unexpected EOF
```

this is the pods list:

```
> kubectl get pods
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
admin-service-54f5d4b568-vbjg6           1/1     Running   345 (5m1s ago)   6d18h
ai-web-594648499d-hq8gx                  1/1     Running   0                58d
chat-server-service-686b4d59f7-x2tq2     2/2     Running   0                24d
cruise-web-74cc96797f-l7g55              1/1     Running   0                68d
cv-render-service-5489d5949c-f6stg       1/1     Running   1 (2d18h ago)    2d18h
cv-service-56cd946c4c-8p4t8              1/1     Running   0                29d
cv-web-647cbccd95-47w7d                  1/1     Running   0                29d
dolphin-music-service-597988cd59-bd92w   1/1     Running   2 (19d ago)      129d
dolphin-post-service-79df79d7f7-zww7x    1/1     Running   0                6d18h
official-website-776b6c6dfd-hfbcx        1/1     Running   0                407d
react-admin-new-6ff54c9889-9cwrf         1/1     Running   0                7d21h
rss-sync-service-77dd845898-wqhp2        1/1     Running   27 (31h ago)     8d
snap-web-66dbcc769f-sl6bs                1/1     Running   0                139d
texhub-server-service-6f8d688c77-kvhgg   1/1     Running   3 (20m ago)      30m
texhub-web-f9fd456f7-47ccc               1/1     Running   0                42h
tool-web-7f97bf5484-28j7r                1/1     Running   0                141d
y-websocket-service-768d56f54b-845kf     1/1     Running   12 (3d19h ago)   6d18h
```

the core.21 file size is 8Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if any of these two alternatives helps you

```
kubectl cp texhub-server-service-6f8d688c77-kvhgg:"/app/core.21" /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/core.21 --retries=-1
```

retries=-1 (any negative value for infinite retrying)

Or

```
kubectl exec texhub-server-service-6f8d688c77-kvhgg cat /app/core.21 > /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/core.21
```

Comment: I have already tried -1, the command will never end. @Raghu

Comment: Does the exec cat also ends up with the same issue, I mean never ends?

Comment: the kubectl exec commands works. @Raghu but it may do a liitle tweak: kubectl exec texhub-server-service-5dc694cf79-npbzt --  cat /app/core.21 > /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/core.21